# sending php array using ajax (no jQuery use) yields bad data at server

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to send php array data using ajax.
Maybe this is not the correct method, so if there is a better one, I will be happy to know.
Anyway, I do not want to use JQuery, but a pure ajax.

I convert the php array to a string (in order to create an array back in the destination php)

```
 $aData = array(
        "Function" => "runRequestedFunction",
        "ReqFunctionName" =>  "Lomba",
        "ReqFunctionData" => 74
        );
 $sendvar = "data=".serialize($aData);
```

Then I  send it using ajax

```
cAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    --- there is some code here for callback  --- 
cAjax.open("POST","doSomthing.php",true);
cAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
cAjax.send("<?php echo $sendvar; ?>");
```

The problem is that the string  $sendvar  contains double quote (") which break the data received in the doSomthing.php file.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$aData= $_POST;
echo "Postinput: "; print_r($aData);echo "</br>";
}    
?>
```

The echo output the follow

```
 Postinput: Array ( [data] => a:3:{s:8: )
```

This is because the string is
 a:3:s:8:"Function";s:20:"runRequestedFunction";s:15:"ReqFunctionName";s:5:"Lomba";s:15:"ReqFunctionData";i:74;}

so the first double quote breaks the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes:

```
cAjax.send('<?php echo $sendvar; ?>');
```

Comment: The problem is that serialize function create the array to a string with double quotes

Comment: `cAjax.send('<?php echo $sendvar; ?>');` single quotes in the send methode.

Comment: Great. Solved it!  Thanks!